# How do I link dynamic prototype cells to different UITableViewControllers?

Tags: uitableview, swift, dynamic, prototype, cell

Pardon me but I'm new to code & Swift.

Can't post an image but I need to link my custom UITableViewController 7 dynamic prototype cells to 7 different UItableviewcontrollers. So far I tried to segue the cell to another UITableViewController, but the rest of the cells are linking to the same place as well. Lets say if i want to link a fast food category to a list of fast food restaurants in a UITableViewController, every other category is also linking to the same UITableViewController.

I'm not quite sure what to do.

My main controller code is as follows:

```
class CategoriesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var category: [Categories] = categoriesData

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return category.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CategoriesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as CategoriesCell

                let categories = category[indexPath.row] as Categories
                cell.textLabel?.text = categories.category
                if let categoryLabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel {
                    categoryLabel.text = categories.category
                }
                return cell
            }
```

This is my `categories.swift` file:

```
class Categories: NSObject {
    var category: String
    init(category: String) {
        self.category = category
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and `categories data.swift`:

```
let categoriesData = [Categories(category:"Restaurants/Cafe"), Categories(category:"Fine Dining"), Categories(category:"Catering"),Categories(category:"Buffet"), Categories(category:"Food Court/Hawker Centre"), Categories(category:"Fast Food"), Categories(category:"Others")]

my categories cell.swift shows the following:

class CategoriesCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can post pictures so we can see as to why you are going that route.

I think you want the sections of the tableview to display different content?

I would suggest:

1. split the table view into the number of sections you want (each section can have a given number of rows)
2. create one UITableViewController class
3. in your

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   }

Set your content based on section & row number

Comment: can't post an image cos my reputation.. lol. i edited my question to be more detailed

Comment: just put them in dropbox or somewhere and provide a link

Comment: Ok so i think i know what you want. You don't want 7 different UITableViewControllers. Can I get access to your project? ill show you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create 7 different prototype cells.
2. Change the reuse identifier of each prototype cell to match one of your categories.
3. Link each prototype cell to a different ViewController with a segue.
4. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, use the category for that row to fetch the correct prototype cell:

   ```
   let categories = category[indexPath.row] as Categories
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(categories.category, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CategoriesCell
   ```

Comment: creating 7 prototypes now but I'm unsure how to write my return cell. how do i write a return cell for 7 cells and how do i write the return for number of rows section?